# Calculating data transfer out in AWS Cloudfront CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Hello and Thanks for reading this.
I am calculating the "data transfer out per month" on AWS cloudfront  for a movie streaming web application (like netflix, etc..) and don't really understand the "data transfer per month".

about the project : 
a typical movie duration : 90 minutes.
a typical movie size : 9,4 GB.
estimated number of movies to be hosted : 5000.
Estimated plays per month : 500000.

So in order to get the good value of "data transfer per month" should i simply 500000(Estimated plays per month) * 9,4 (a typical movie size) or i am getting something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want de deliver 4500 T / month, you should ask AWS for a discount.
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/ says:
*Discounted pricing is available for customers willing to commit to a minimum of 10 TB of data transfer per month for 12 months or longer. Discounts vary based on the amount of the commitment.

Interested in signing up for discounted pricing? Please contact us.*

They also suggest to look at the regions where you want to deliver the data: You have a lower price class when you only want edge locations in United States, Canada and Europe.

Also look at https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/video-streams/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=3.
It seems you get better rates when using this service and not something from a S3 bucket+cloudfront.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Actually i was surprised by the high cost ( $ 158702.71) for 4700TB cloud front.
so if a video of 9.4gb is played 500000 times, is it going to be a data transfer of (500000 * 9.4 ) as i calculated before ?

Comment: Without special discounts, only United States, Canada and Europe costs 10*85+40*80+100*60+350*40+524*30+3676*25 = 131.670 , so you need 40 c / movie. I don't know if you can use https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/video-streams , /pricing/?nc=sn&loc=3 (about 0.01/Gb) is 47.000 (10c/movie).